# Unique Specification of Ellipse Given Two Arbitrary Axes Lengths and Axes Orientation?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Without loss of generality, let an ellipse be centered on the origin (0,0) with the major axis aligned with the 45 degree line (y=x).

Given the lengths of the major and minor axes, the ellipse is uniquely specified. But if the only information given are the lengths of two arbitrarily-oriented perpendicular axes, and the angle between one of the said axis and the major axis, can be the ellipse be specified uniquely?

For example, if it is known the ellipse intersects the x-axis at 5, and intersects the y-axis at 5, can be ellipse be uniquely specified? (Remember the ellipse is centered at (0,0) and the major axis is along y=x).

Answer (score 1):

No, the ellipse as described is not uniquely specified.

For your example, any ellipse in the family 
$$
\frac{(x-y)^2}{a^2} - \frac{(x+y)^2}{b^2} =1
$$
with 
$$\frac{1}{a^2} +\frac{1}{b^2}  = \frac{1}{5^2} $$
will pass thru $(5,0)$ and $(0,5)$ One of these is a nice circle of radius $5$, another (with $a = \frac{25}{3}, b=\frac{25}{4}$) is an ellipse with axes in ratio 4:3.

Comment: Thanks Mark Fischler. If there is no symmetry - if it is known that the ellipse pass thru $(5,0)$ and $(0,6)$, the ellipse would still not be unique, correct?

Comment: Incorrect. The fact that major axis is along the 45 deg line, and the symmetry of the point (5,0) & (0,5) makes the example a rather pathological case with non-unique solutions.